# How to synchronize threads at regular intervals?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have problems synchronizing several threads at regular intervals without consuming too much cpu while waiting.

I have a main thread, and several calculations threads that are all in the form :

```
CalcThread()   // x N threads
{
  loop{
    - do some calc stuff (variable but finite duration).
    - wait until main thread give a "continue" signal.
  }
}

MainThread()
{
  loop{
    - wait for all calc threads to be in waiting state.
    - do some calc synthesis stuff.
    - send a "continue" signal to calc threads.
  }
}
```

For the moment I make my threads waiting for each others looping the std::this_thread::yield() instruction with some condition on atomic shared flags. It works, BUT these loops are very CPU consuming.

There must be another solution, probably using mutex and condition_variable, but I am new to this, and all my attempt leads to failure...

Does anyone have an idea ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use something like [this](https://pastebin.com/F8P7qDav)

Comment: Thx. Finally, after numerous tries, I figured out how to use condition variables. I just have to use different ones depending on who is waiting who. And to use notify_all ; because in my case, I did not understand that notify_one only notify 1 random thread, and when I want to send from the numerous calc threads to the unique main thread, I have to be sure to target the main thread and not a random calc thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A condition variable is exactly what you want. Have your calc threads use [`std::condition_variable::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) to have them block until woken up by your main thread. Have the main thread call [`std::condition_variable::notify_all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_all) to unblock all of the calc threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I thought, but I cannot figure out how to implement this, despite reading the c++ documentation... I made several tries, but none of them works... Do you have an example to provide ? Or could you complete my pseudo code with the right instructions and mutex declaration ?

Because there are two "waiting stuff" : the main thread waits for all calc threads to be ready. And then, ni return, the calc threads all wait for the signal of the main thread.